# How to create URI/URL using MultiValueMap for parameters?

Tags: java, spring, url, uri

I have multimap of parameters, like this:

```
{
    keyA: ["2+4", "4+8"],
    keyB: ["Some words with special chars #ąęć"]
}
```

as spring `MultiValueMap` and I'm trying to create URI from this, I tried to use

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
           .fromUriString(baseUri).path(somePath)
           .queryParams(params.getQueryParameters())
           .build().encode().toUri();
```

It seems to work for special chars, but it still does think that `+` sign is a space, I want to encode all parameters, is there existing solution for this other than manually encoding each value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Spring 5.0, this is discussed in detail in [[SPR-16860] Spring is inconsistent in the encoding/decoding of URLs](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16860) issue. More or less it boils down to this:

> From an RFC 3986 perspecitve, "+" is a legal character. By default the RestTemplate leaves it as is.

`UriComponents.encode()` will leave `+` sign as is, to stay complaint with the RFC 3986. If you need it encoded one suggestion is to use [`UriUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html):

```
String value = "A+B=C";
value = UriUtils.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // A%2BB%3DC
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
       .queryParam("test", value)
       .build(true)
       .toUri();
```

There is a change coming 5.0.8 as part of [[SPR-17039] Support stricter encoding of URI variables in UriComponents](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17039) which introduces new [`UriComponentsBuilder.encode()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#encode--) method. It should be enough to move `encode()` before `build()` in your example:

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
       .fromUriString(baseUri).path(somePath)
       .queryParams(params.getQueryParameters())
       .encode()
       .build()
       .toUri();
```

Comment: So with spring 5.0.8 using `.encode()` before `build` should use that more strict encoding? As for me it still does leave `+` sign.

Comment: This seems to only work for params like `{keyA: {keyA}}` and then using `expand({keyA: ["2+4", "4+8"]})` but I already have map of all parameters.